# Using bootstrap brand colours for text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a form using bootstrap and I would like to make some of the text a "brand color" like you see in the buttons. I know about the text colors available using text-primary etc.
However, I would like to use the button colors for the text.

I tried this

```
<style>
  em {
    background-color: @brand-danger;
  }
</style>
```

Also I found the default values for bootstrap colors here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less but i just want to use their variable or class without manually using the hex value.
What is the way to use their color?

Comment: U need less compiler, and convert your less files to css files

Comment: Have you got the bootstrap less files in your project?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys! I don't have the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create your own LESS/SASS source, tie it in with bootstrap, create your custom styles, then run it through the compiler. The variables, such as `@brand-primary`/`$brand-primary`, are only meaningful in the LESS/SASS languages.

And, since BS4 is going SASS, I suggest (if you're going down that path) you do as well.

---

Example (I'll use LESS since it's more common):

1. [Download](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) the Bootstrap LESS source
2. Create a new LESS stylesheet for your project and place it along side the others (such as `bootstrap.less`, `mixins.less`, etc.)
3. Add a reference to your new stylesheet within `bootstrap.less` (this can be done using the `@import` directive, but make sure to place it towards the bottom).
4. [Compile](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt) your new styles.